# How to disable scrolling (other than overflow:hidden)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, overflow

I need to stop users from being able to scroll on my page.  I have divs positioned off screen which will be animated into view later.  I'm already using overflow:hidden so that there's no scroll bars, but you can still use the mouse wheel to get over there. I would like to turn that off somehow.  Also it would be convenient if it were able to be turned on and off dynamically.  With using if statements i could re-enable scrolling later if necessary.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: elm.onscroll=function(e){e.target.scrollTop=0;}

Comment: Just a suggestion.. `position:relative` and `left:-9999px;` ?

Comment: it already is positioned like that, Josh.  & dan, can i just put that in the head with jquery?

Comment: you would probably need to use on() to watch over, say, the body tag (and all it's children), but i'm not 100% sure onscroll bubbles. you can apply it one-at-a-time to each locked-down element, or to a bunch at once using a jQuery selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'll be doing animations later why not trigger a few set up animations at the ready step of your document? This will minimize the element size and prevent it from overflowing bounds.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#isCausingScrolling").animate({width: "toggle"},{duration:2000});    
});
```

`width: "toggle"` causes the element to collapse from x width down to 0 or vice versa; duration is simply how long you want the animation to take in milliseconds.

```
$("#Button1").on("click", function(){
    $("#isCausingScrolling").animate({width: "toggle"},{duration:2000});
});
```

Will size the elements back to the normal width or collapse them again from some type of input (button in this case).